# How are the non-IK bones hidden in MBLab, and how can I reveal them?

Tags: armature, bones, visibility, manuel-bastioni-lab

I'm doing some tricky armature work with clothing; and I need to deform according to specific bones. However, my initial mesh was created using MB Lab, which, while great, hides all of the deforming bones when *Use Inverse Kinematics* and *Use Muscles* are selected.

For the life of me, I can't figure out where these non-IK bones are, or how they're working. The trick explained to me in the past was to duplicate the armature, remove all bones that I don't want to use, Automatic-Weights-Parent my mesh to the armature, then change parents without changing weights to the old armature. This would be doable, if I could find the normal bones.

They aren't hidden in any typical fashion. <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd> and other tricks do not help. I'm beginning to wonder if they're still "bones" in the conventional sense, and I'm having a very hard time finding anything on the web.

Comment: Anything showing disabled under the armature's Object Data Properties in the bone layers?

Comment: That was it! I've fallen so far behind with how armatures work... I just needed to change layers. If you feel like turning this into a full response, I'll accept it as a solution.

Comment: heh. I was about to write it up, but @JohnEason deserves the votes.

Comment: Ok. Now added as an answer thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if anything is disabled in the bone layers under the armature's Object Data Properties.

Comment: Specifically, the first bone layer has the deformation bones, the 2nd has the IK bones, and  if you have muscle bones they go on the 3rd layer.

Comment: To expand on this for anyone who is in exactly the same situation I was, MBLab and Blender 3.0 now divide the bones into layers for organization--which is cool, because there are a ton of them. Marty expanded further on this. By duplicating the armature, removing all of the bones of the second layer, and parenting to it with automatic weights; then reparenting to the original, we can achieve proper IK-controlled mesh deformation of clothing.

Answer (score 2):

- Select Skeleton
- Go to *Pose Mode*
- Select *Object Data Properties* (the green running man)
- Under *Skeleton/Layers*<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Click</kbd> the second white dot, this shows and hides the bones

This is using Blender 3.1.2 and MB-Lab 1.7.8